# Creating a barchart connecting opening and closing prices

Tags: r, quantmod

I saw in a book a monochrome barchart where closing prices are connected to next days' opening prices. Kind of like this https://www.trade.education/wp-content/uploads/ohlc-chart-bar-chart.jpg , but the opening and closing prices connected, so that it looks like one continuous line. Is it possible to do it in R? The closest I can come is with `barChart` with `theme='white.mono'` however opening and closing prices are not connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely clear what you want, but here are some possibilities using `ggplot`.

```
# grab sample data
library(quantmod)
aapl <- getSymbols("AAPL", from="2015-06-01",auto.assign=FALSE)
names(aapl) <- sub("[^\\.]+\\.","",names(aapl))   # remove `AAPL.` from column names
df <- data.frame(date=index(aapl),aapl)           # ggplot needs a data.frame
# basic OHLC plot    
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)    # for date_format
ggplot(df, aes(x=date))+
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=Low, ymax=High, color=ifelse(Close>Open,"Gain","Loss")))+
  geom_segment(aes(xend=date-0.3, y=Open,  yend=Open))+
  geom_segment(aes(xend=date+0.3, y=Close, yend=Close))+
  scale_color_manual(guide="none",values=c(Gain="green", Loss="red"))+
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b-%Y"))+
  labs(x="",y="", title="AAPL")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
# Intraday/Overnight plot
library(reshape2)   # for melt(...)
df.melt <- melt(subset(df,select=c(date,Open,Close)),id="date",value.name="price")
df.melt <- df.melt[order(df.melt$date),]
ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=date, y=price)) + 
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b-%Y"))+
  labs(x="",y="", title="AAPL")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
# same, color coded
ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=date, y=price)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=ifelse(c(diff(price),NA)>0,"Gain","Loss"), group=NA))+
  scale_color_manual(guide="none",values=c(Gain="Green", Loss="Red"))+
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b-%Y"))+
  labs(x="",y="", title="AAPL")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

*Edit*: Response to OPs comment.

Like this?

```
df.melt <- melt(subset(df,select=c(date,Open,High,Low,Close)),id="date",value.name="price")
df.melt <- df.melt[order(df.melt$date),]
ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=date, y=price)) + 
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b-%Y"))+
  labs(x="",y="", title="AAPL")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It is close, but it looks like that this chart only shows the opening and closing prices, missing day lows and highs.

Answer (score 1):

The link in your post displays a simple bar chart. This is the standard display in `quantmod`.

You are probably referring to [Kagi charts](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/trading/07/kagi_chart.asp), which are constructed in a different way. They represent a continuous line with certain steps. These steps may look as if the closing price of one day is connected to the opening of the next day, but this interpretation is wrong. It is is not just a graphical issue, those are fundamentally different chart types without gaps.

I'm not aware that Kagi chart types are available in the `quantmod` package, and I would advise not to use them unless you are certain about the way they represent the data.

Comment: Thank you. It was not Kagi charts.